# DB2 Query to get month number from 1 to 12 as 12 rows

Tags: db2

DB2 Query get month number from 1 to 12 as 12 rows.

I want the result as follows

1. 1
2. 2
3. 3
4. 4
5. 5
6. 6
7. 7
8. 8
9. 9
10. 10
11. 11
12. 12

Please do let me know your thoughts.

Comment: How have you started, what is your SELECT statement? Have you investigated the WITH clause?

Comment: with clause uses a table to iterate but I dont have any table to iterate with, all I need is 12 rows values from 1 to 12.

Comment: Define the table on the fly!

Answer (score 1):

The [common table expression](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0059217.html) (WITH clause) lets you define a table to select from. Something like the following can be done:

```
with dummy(id) as (
    select 1 from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1    
    union all
    select id + 1 from dummy where id < 12
)
select id from dummy
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have + 12 columns into all your tables in your all schemas, you can do it:

```
select rownumber() over() as mymonth from syscolumns
fetch first 12 rows only
```

Answer (score 0):

Other method:

```
with AllMonth(mymonth) as (
    values (1), (2), (3), (4),(5), (6),(7), (8), (9), (10),(11), (12)
)
select mymonth from AllMonth
```

or without with :

```
select mymonth from (
values (1), (2), (3), (4),(5), (6),(7), (8), (9), (10),(11), (12)
) AllMonth(mymonth)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other method:

```
with AllMonth(mymonth) as (
Select 1 from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 
union all
Select 2 from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 
union all
Select 3 from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 
union all
Select 4 from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 
union all
Select 5 from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 
union all
Select 6 from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 
union all
Select 7 from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 
union all
Select 8 from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 
union all
Select 9 from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 
union all
Select 10 from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 
union all
Select 11 from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 
union all
Select 12 from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 
)
select mymonth from AllMonth
```